# capture screen as it looks like

Tags: iphone

iam doing one application.In that Im using one imageview with image and add one view with sone clear holes.Means through that holes we can see the background image.So my problem is i want to capture that total screen (imageview with this holes view).Iam using below code but it's not working.

```
- (UIImage*)captureView:(UIView *)yourView {
CGRect rect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
[yourView.layer renderInContext:context];
UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
return image;
 }
```

but it's not working.

Comment: What you're passing in yourView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This IS how we do:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(yourView.bounds.size, yourView.opaque, 0.0);
[yourView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *LastImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this to take your screeShoT

```
-(UIImage*)getScreenShot
{
    CGSize screenSize = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame].size;

    //CGSize screenSize = CGSizeMake(1024, 768);
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpaceRef = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();

    CGContextRef ctx = CGBitmapContextCreate(nil, screenSize.width, 416, 8, 4*(int)screenSize.width, colorSpaceRef, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast);
    CGContextTranslateCTM(ctx, 0.0, screenSize.height);
    CGContextScaleCTM(ctx, 1.0, -1.0);

    [(CALayer*)self.yourView.layer renderInContext:ctx];

    CGImageRef cgImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(ctx);
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgImage];
    CGImageRelease(cgImage);
    CGContextRelease(ctx);

    return image;

}
```